# CakePHP and XAMPP error on PDO connection

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pdo, xampp

I'm trying to install a CakePHP application ([digigas](https://github.com/Digigas/digigas)) on a Windows 10 machine. I'm using a fresh installations of XAMPP, with uncommented `extension=php_intl.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`.

When I launch the application I get this error

```
Fatal Error (256): DboMysql - Selected driver is not enabled [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 139]
```

This code instead works correctly:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
```

The same application, on a LAMP server, run properly.

I hope is not a duplicate, I have found a lot of post on this arguments but no one has helped me... 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application that you are trying to install uses CakePHP 1.3, which btw is totally outdated, and support for it has been discontinued months ago, there won't even be any security updates anymore, so I'd suggest that you rethink using that application!

That being said, CakePHP 1.3 doesn't use PDO, but the (also already deprecated, and as of PHP 7 completely removed) MySQL extension, ie `php_mysql.dll`.

**http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php**

Comment: You're absolutely right, activating `extension=php_mysql.dll` now everything works! Thank you also for the advice regarding the rethinking of this application...